# Drupal service module Json Parser

Tags: json, drupal, drupal-6, drupal-modules

I am using Drupal6 and try to implement Service module here. I also installed json_server, But when i am trying to configure it gives  following error. Anybody help me for this.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is not an error. It's just an informational message.
Note that if you experience problems it might be related to undocumented changes in the latest releases of the Services module. I recently ran into many problems because I was following Services 2.0 example code and there are substantial changes in Services 3.0.